# Combobox Binding in Windows Store using Caliburn

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to bind a combobox using Caliburn and the following code:

***yyyView.xaml***

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Filters"></ComboBox>
```

***yyyViewModel.xaml***

```
private string selectedFilter;

public BindableCollection<string> Filters
{
    get
    {
        return new BindableCollection<string>(
                 new string[]{ "All", "Last Month", "Last Week", "Yesterday" });
    }
}

public string SelectedFilter
{
    get { return selectedFilter; }
    set
    {
        selectedFilter = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedFilter);
    }
}
```

Using this code, I'm getting an ***ArgumentNullException*** on ***App.xaml.cs*** on the ***GetInstance*** method.

I'm new to MVVM, Caliburn and XAML, but I've read somewhere there were some kind of behaviors (**Blend Behaviors**, I believe) dropped in WinRT development.

Is that the problem? How can I solve this?

Thank you

EDIT:

***App.xaml.cs***

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLogger(type);
    container = new WinRTContainer();
    container.RegisterWinRTServices();
    container.PerRequest<aaaViewModel>();
    container.PerRequest<xxxViewModel>();
    container.PerRequest<yyyViewModel>();
    container.PerRequest<zzzViewModel>();
}
```

***App.xaml***

```
<caliburn:CaliburnApplication
    x:Class="yyyStoreApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:yyyApp"
    xmlns:caliburn="using:Caliburn.Micro"
    xmlns:converters="using:yyyApp.Converters"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/CustomStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <converters:ImageFilePathConverter x:Key="ImageFilePath"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</caliburn:CaliburnApplication>
```

Comment: Can you post your App.xaml and any relevant code-behind? It sounds like something is not being constructed correctly, your Caliburn binding notwithstanding.

Comment: I haven't changed App.xaml for this View and other Views of the App are working. On the code behind I have registered the ViewModel:

`container.PerRequest<yyyViewModel>();`

I can enter the view and see other binded elements, only the combobox isn't working properly. It's empty and the exception is thrown when I click it.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably not registered the view model in the `Configure` method overload in your `App` implementation. Please have a look at the `// TODO` part in the `App` code in the [WinRT documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20WinRT&referringTitle=Documentation).

This is apparently intended behaviour, but has caused some confusion, as can be seen in the discussion forum and issue tracker on CodePlex, see [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/287), [here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/280) and [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/432882).

Basically, you should be well off simply by adding this line to the `Configure` method:

```
container.PerRequest<yyyViewModel>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've registered the ViewModel on the App. I even have other binding elements on the same view that are working.

The problem must be something else. 
Sorry if I didn't make it clear: **The problem happens when I click the combobox. And also it starts empty**

Comment: @Silva I have implemented your code according to what you have specified, but I cannot reproduce your error. The only thing I see is that the `ComboBox` items cannot be properly displayed out-of-the-box, so I have added an `ItemTemplate` to the `ComboBox`:         `<ComboBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/></DataTemplate></ComboBox.ItemTemplate>`. I honestly don't think this will help in your case, though, so please publish relevant parts of your *App.xaml.cs* (e.g. `Configure` and `OnLaunched` methods) to facilitate error tracking.

Comment: @Gustafsson, I have updated the initial post.
P.S.: I have managed to make this work using explicit binding, i.e.:
`<ComboBox x:Name="Filters" ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFilter, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

However, I believe Caliburn should do that for me...

Comment: @Silva Thanks for the code. Yes, CM should manage these bindings through convention, and my code (which is along the same lines as yours) work as intended. Which CM version are you using? Could you also publish your `OnLaunched` method?